# Running Linux commands in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows

how do I know what package was installed in my local windows cmd that runs Linux commands? It's because I want to install the same tool on my other machine and I can't recall if I've installed something.

```
C:\>awk
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:          GNU long options:
        -f progfile             --file=progfile
        -F fs                   --field-separator=fs
        -v var=val              --assign=var=val
        -m[fr] val
        -W compat               --compat
        -W copyleft             --copyleft
        -W copyright            --copyright
        -W dump-variables[=file]        --dump-variables[=file]
        -W exec=file            --exec=file
        -W gen-po               --gen-po
        -W help                 --help
        -W lint[=fatal]         --lint[=fatal]
        -W lint-old             --lint-old
        -W non-decimal-data     --non-decimal-data
        -W profile[=file]       --profile[=file]
        -W posix                --posix
        -W re-interval          --re-interval
        -W source=program-text  --source=program-text
        -W traditional          --traditional
        -W usage                --usage
        -W use-lc-numeric       --use-lc-numeric
        -W version              --version

To report bugs, see node `Bugs' in `gawk.info', which is
section `Reporting Problems and Bugs' in the printed version.

gawk is a pattern scanning and processing language.
By default it reads standard input and writes standard output.

Examples:
        gawk '{ sum += $1 }; END { print sum }' file
        gawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Did you install MinGW?

Comment: @Lord_Gestalter nope, just found it's GOW (GNU on Windows) using ghostdog74's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can execute `awk` on the command prompt, check your Windows PATH variable.

`echo %PATH%`

Comment: Found it - GOW (GNU on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

follow steps given in following link 
to use unix/linux commands at the windows command

[How to use Unix/Linux commands at the Windows command prompt](http://www.askstudent.com/tips/how-to-use-unixlinux-commands-at-the-windows-command-prompt/)